# Ar-js and a-frame look-controls . The object is placed with angle if adding look controls to a-entity

Tags: augmented-reality, aframe, ar.js

I'm using Ar-js based on marker (Hiro marker).
Here is working example:
https://codepen.io/taime/pen/QWjExPe

```
<a-scene embedded arjs>
    <a-marker preset="hiro">
        <a-entity look-controls position="0 -0.5 0" rotation="0 0 0" scale="1 1 1">
            <a-box position="0 0 0" rotation="0 0 0" color="#4CC3D9" shadow></a-box>
        </a-entity>
    </a-marker>
    <a-entity camera></a-entity>
</a-scene>
```

The object (box) is placed with angle (rotated) but it should be horizontal!
Without `look-controls` it is horizontal...
I test it on iPhone 6S!
iOS 13.3.1

Is it bug? How to set it up horizontal with look-controls? (I need to rotate the object with touch gestures thats why I'm using `look-controls`)

p.s. The **Hiro marker** is here https://raw.githubusercontent.com/AR-js-org/AR.js/master/data/images/hiro.png

Comment: Github issue here: https://github.com/AR-js-org/AR.js/issues/85

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The box is fine when tested on PC/Laptop but not on Mobile. After some test, using version `1.0.0` solve the issue for now

```
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.0.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
```

Although on my devices (xiaomi redmi note 8 pro), i can ONLY rotate the box horizontally (can't rotate vertically). But it is fine on PC/Laptop.

Hope `aframe` solve this issue

Comment: This bug happens only when a-frame is with ar-js!